# NameError: Name is 'feed' not defined

Tags: python

I've got this these two code snippets [from a webinar(slide 7 and 8 respectively)](http://www.slideshare.net/afalk42/xbrl-us-altova-webinar)

The **first** one finds a desired `URL` *i have tested it and it works*:

```
def SECdownload(year, month):
    import os
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    root = None
    feedFile = None
    feedData = None
    good_read = False
    itemIndex = 0
    edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
    print( edgarFilingsFeed )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
    try:
        feedFile = urlopen( edgarFilingsFeed ) # urlopen will not work (python 3) needs from urllib.request import urlopen
        try:
            feedData = feedFile.read()
            good_read = True
        finally:
            feedFile.close()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
```

and the **second** one is supposed to parse the `RSS Feed` to find `ZIP` filenames:

```
#Downloading the data - parsing the RSS feed to extract the ZIP file enclosure filename
# Process RSS feed and walk through all items contained
for item in feed.entries:
    print( item[ "summary" ], item[ "title" ], item[ "published" ] )
    try:
        # Identify ZIP file enclosure, if available
        enclosures = [ l for l in item[ "links" ] if l[ "rel" ] == "enclosure" ]
        if ( len( enclosures ) > 0 ):
            # ZIP file enclosure exists, so we can just download the ZIP file
            enclosure = enclosures[0]
            sourceurl = enclosure[ "href" ]
            cik = item[ "edgar_ciknumber" ]
            targetfname = target_dir+cik +' - ' +sourceurl.split('/')[-1]
            retry_counter = 3
            while retry_counter > 0:
                good_read = downloadfile( sourceurl, targetfname )
                if good_read:
                    break
                else:
                    print( "Retrying:", retry_counter )
                    retry_counter -= 1
    except:
        pass
```

However whenever i try to run the second module i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Py_env\df2.py", line 3, in <module>
    for item in feed.entries:
NameError: name 'feed' is not defined
```

What am i not understanding in the webinar right? And if i must define feed i have literally no idea how to do it **while keeping a logical linkage to the data the first code snippet provides**!

(On the sidenote this is a webinar from a reputable software vendor so how it is possible to have mistakes(?) there's something i am doing wrong...)

Comment: Look in the right column on the slide you got that from. The first function gets you the RSS data (`feedData`). The next slide expects you to instantiate feedparser on your own, feed it the data, then feedparser should have the iteratble objects for function two. The slides are giving you examples, not a step by step.

Comment: @nerdwaller i think that makes some sence to me. Well how can i instantiate the feedparser on my own and feed him the data ( i rank amauter in Python)

Comment: Ohhhh damn i think i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrated from a comment.

As your output is showing you and you noticed, `feed` wasn't defined nor was it shown to you in the slides.  It looks as though the slide share is expecting you to make a logical jump, and they do point out in the right column that `feedparser` is an easy way to parse... feeds (RSS Feeds).

So they are expecting that you can adapt the `feedData` you found in your first function and can dump it into a method from `feedparser`.

As you can see in various examples online (such as [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html)), this can be done from the string you got:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> rawdata = """<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Sample Feed</title>
</channel>
</rss>"""
>>> d = feedparser.parse(rawdata)
>>> d['feed']['title']
u'Sample Feed'
```

Using that, I bet you can see where it goes (rather than me telling you).

*as @PatrickCollins pointed out, this is kindof crappy examples for python, but that shouldn't get in your way as you're learning it.*

Comment: @Codo - Glad to hear it, enjoy learning python.  It's a nice language.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is like the error message implies: you haven't defined any variable named `feed` that's in scope when the second snippet executes. Either their code omitted something, or you missed a part that was crucial.

That aside, the formatting on this code is really dodgy and not at all idiomatic Python. You're probably better off looking for a new snippet.